# serial execution in Java-ee

Tags: java, jms, executorservice, java-ee-7

I have some incoming concurrent requests that should be processed in serial. I have attempted to achieve this by converting the requests to messages and post to a jms queue. Then Use an mdb to process the queue.

Using vendor specific config, I understand I can limit mdb to one instance, but what is the recommended and portable way to solve this problem?

Edit: forgot to mention I don't really need the features of jms (reliability etc).

Comment: What you mean by Serial . do you want execute in Single thread ?. or do you want to start the process the serial ( assume you have 50 task and you have two threads , thread1 picks job1 thread2 picks job2 before job1 completes thread2 can pick the Job3 and move on). so you want more threads or only one thread

Comment: i want to run job1 to completion, before touching job2

Comment: Then what is the problem using SingleThreadExecutors ?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()

Comment: If they are ok to use according to ee-spec, are they? I was more thinking of using ManagedExecutorService together with a singleton-ejb holding a ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Comment: To me it is simple case, your concurrent requests has to be submit to the singleThreadExecutor. and it would process the same order it receives the request. See my answer below. It is also important to know how many jobs would be pending at any given point of time to avoid long wating / memory consumption problems

Comment: I Just feel you are answering the question in java-se context and not convincing me the answer applies/is a best practice for java-ee

Comment: Agreed. I just noticed you did tagged as Java-ee. but you haven't mentioned about this in your question. If you required to use the Managed Transactions and all Java-ee feature while performing your tasks. yes you have to use ManagedExecutorService

Comment: np, happened to me alot of times, only read the question and not the subject. Thanks for help anyways :)

Comment: You can block using Future.get() even in ManagedExecutorService(). see my updated answer.i did quick test with Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3) it works fine ( not in ManagedExecutorService).

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have Job like this.

```
class LogJob implements Runnable{
    private final String name;
    public LogJob(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(" Starting ."+name);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(" End ."+name);
    }
}
```

It is just display starting and ending Job. Placed sleep for demo

Create a list of Jobs

```
        ArrayList<LogJob> jobs = new ArrayList<LogJob>();
        for ( int i=0;i<10;i++){
            LogJob job = new LogJob("Job"+i);
            jobs.add(job);
        }
```

Let see how to process in serial

```
   ExecutorService singleThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        for (Iterator<LogJob> iterator = jobs.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            singleThread.execute(iterator.next());
        }
        singleThread.shutdown();
```

This will provide an output.

```
Starting .Job0
 End .Job0
 Starting .Job1
 End .Job1
 Starting .Job2
 End .Job2
 Starting .Job3
 End .Job3
 Starting .Job4
 End .Job4
 Starting .Job5
 End .Job5
 Starting .Job6
 End .Job6
 Starting .Job7
 End .Job7
 Starting .Job8
 End .Job8
 Starting .Job9
 End .Job9
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on conversation in comment, i came to know you have to use this in Java-EE environment.
As you said you have to use `ManagedExecutorService` . How ever you dont need to use singleton Ejb and  ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

You can implement you Jobs as Callable and you can block further processing using Future.get()

```
String name = managedService.submit(iterator.next()).get();
```

From [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29)

```
    If you would like to immediately block waiting for a task, 
you can use constructions of the form result = exec.submit(aCallable).get();
```